# How to use over 4 channels images for Unet classify training

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am using zhixuhao/unet

I'm training a eight-channel image for classify which is separate. 1 x 3channel, 5 x 1channel
[image]

How should I arrange the array for input to Unet? Put it all together in array with numpy.concatenate? Or directly in the layers?I'm new in Deep Learning and computer vision and I got this question bugging me.

And which dataGenerator conform to my state

I tried concatenate them and save to .npy be 18 channel file,but ImageDataGenerator cannot receive 18 channel data

and I tried concatenate six image image_datagen.flow_from_directory but it cannot distinguish classes_folder

Comment: extend the first layer to be 5-channel rather than 3-channel